# Before Update Trigger doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I created this PL/pgSQL trigger function in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER question31
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON public."Semester"
FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.trigger31();
```

---

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION public.trigger31()
        RETURNS trigger 
    AS 
    $$
    begin
        if(TG_OP='UPDATE')then
            if (new.start_date>(select p.end_date from "Semester" p where p.semester_id in(select s.semester_id-1 from "Semester" s where s.end_date=old.end_date))
            or new.start_date>=new.end_date) then

             return old;

            else
               if new.semester_status='past'

                        if old.semester_status='present' then
                            return new;
                        elsif old.semester_status='future' then
                            return old;
                        else
                            return new;
                        end if;

                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
        RETURN new;
    end;
    $$
    language 'plpgsql'
```

My table before `Update` :

```
 ________________________________________________________
| semester_id | start_date | end_date   | semester_status |
-------------- ------------ ------------ -----------------
|      1      | 2010-1-10  | 2010-12-10 |      past       |
-------------- ------------ ------------ -----------------
|      2      | 2011-1-10  | 2011-12-10 |      present    |
-------------- ------------ ------------ -----------------
|      3      | 2012-1-10  | 2012-12-10 |      future     |
-------------- ------------ ------------ -----------------
|      4      | 2013-1-10  | 2013-12-10 |      future     |
-------------- ------------ ------------ -----------------
```

I want `Update semester_id=2` like this :

```
Update "Semester" 
set semester_status = 'past'
where semester_id = 2
```

I would wait to change the `'semester_status'` from `'present'` to `'past'`

We have the same results and at try to `Update start_date`.

I mean that the `update` doesn't work right.

> How can i fix this?

Comment: `select s.semester_id-1 from "Semester" s where s.end_date=old.end_date` returns `1`, `select p.end_date from "Semester" p where p.semester_id in (1)` returns `2010-12-10`, `2011-1-10 > 2010-12-10` - `true` - update not performed. It means that `update` works exactly as you programed it. This question not about programming but about business logic of your application IMO.

Comment: Yes that's why i return old; look and the oter rows where is my fault there?

Comment: You are probably running into one of the `RETURN OLD;` branches. Debug to find out where.